# Why is this bash variable blank when taking output from mysql?

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to take the output from a MySQL query in bash and use it in a bash variable, but it keeps coming up blank when used in the script, but works perfectly from the terminal. What's wrong here?

I've tried changing the way the statement is written and changing the name of the variable just in case it was somehow reserved. I've also done a significant amount of searching but it turns out if you but 'bash', 'blank', and 'variable' in the search it usually comes up with some version of how to test for blank variables which I already know how to do.

```
tempo=$(mysql -u "$dbuser" -p"$dbpass" -D "$database" -t -s -r -N -B -e "select user from example where user='$temp' > 0;")
printf "the output should be: $tempo" # This is a test statement
```

The end result should be that the `$tempo` variable should either contain a user name from the database or be blank if there isn't one.

Comment: seems sql is not valid `user = '$temp' > 0`, also what is `$temp` and beware of the risk of sql injection

Comment: in user='$temp' > 0, $temp was a user supplied variable. It was incorrect so I supplied the corrected variable. I've used shellcheck to determine if there were any obvious errors in my bash script but it sadly doesn't catch errors like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some error with your sql statement at `user = '$temp' > 0`.

But to get the result from MySql you have to redirect the standard error (`stderr`) to the standard output (`stdout`), you should use 2>&1.

Most probably you will run into MySql error but try running this on terminal.

tempo=$((mysql -u "$dbuser" -p"$dbpass" -D "$database" -t -s -r -N -B -e "select user from example where user='$temp' > 0;") 2>&1)

Comment: Nice catch on the typo I'm. I fixed '$temp'. I also tried the solution out and it works in the terminal like the original but not in the script. When I do it at the terminal I change all of the variables to their functioning answers but that is the only difference I can think of. I'll try it with variables instead.

Comment: Udate-  username="da";dbuser="test";dbpass="password";database="test001";tempo=$(mysql -u "$dbuser" -p"$dbpass" -D "$database" -t -s -r -N -B -e "select user from example where user='$username' > 0;"); echo $tempo

This functions as expected in the terminal but not in the test.sh script.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to echo the result of the sql query like this:

```
tempo=$(echo $(mysql -u "$dbuser" -p"$dbpass" -D "$database"  -s -N -B -e "select user from example where user='$username' > 0;"))
```

Now I'm left with logic issues but I think I can handle that.